# Hide meta box for everything BUT a certain custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I need to retain tag taxonomy for a single custom post type, but am struggling with it.

Is there a way to remove this meta box for everything BUT?

---

`remove_meta_box('tagsdiv-post_tag', 'post', 'normal');`

Will remove the tags from normal posts (desired), but it means they're also removed from ALL custom post types. I can remove the meta box for individual custom post types, like so:

`remove_meta_box('tagsdiv-post_tag', 'cars', 'normal');`

`remove_meta_box('tagsdiv-post_tag', 'hotels', 'normal');`

etc.

But that means I have to leave tags available on normal posts (undesired).

So I guess I want something like this, to remove the meta box from everything apart from (e.g.) `airports`:

`remove_meta_box('tagsdiv-post_tag', '!airports', 'normal');`

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you just want to remove the meta box but not the tags taxonomy of these CPTs? Also: Have you tried removing it everywhere and then just adding it back for this one CPT?

Comment: Have you tried using Advanced Custom Fields? It is THE most incredible plugin you will ever use for Custom Fields and once you have created your Custom Post Type, you have the option of switching off certain meta boxes.

Comment: I'm using ACF, but it doesn't help with tags, unless all you need to do is select from a pre-defined list of tags - I looked into this first :) @kraftner - this would be fine - is there a true 'add_meta_box' for this context? Docs seemed to indicate it's usage was different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just turn off the default tags capability then register a tags taxonomy specific to the custom post type?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

```
register_taxonomy(
  'my_custom_post_type_tags',
  'my_custom_post_type',
  array(
    'label'        => __( 'Tags' ),
    'rewrite'      => false,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'capabilities' => array( 'edit_terms' => 'manage_categories' )
  )
);
```

Comment: This is technically an improvement - not quite what I asked for - but it is the best way to achieve what I need so I'm going to mark this is correct. For anyone that needs to do exactly what I requested then @The Sufi's answer does the job (with my correction).

Thanks Joey, works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve removing metaboxes from all post type screens except specific ones. This is how I done it. Might be a bit overrated, lol

Firstly, you will need to get a list of all public post type registered. This is done by using [`get_post_types`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types). You will need to use the parameter `'public' => true`, otherwise all post types will be returned, which is unnecessary.

Secondly, you need to remove or exclude the post type you don't want the metabox to be removed from.

Thirdly, you need to pass the returned list of post type names to the [`remove_meta_box()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) function to remove the specific meta box from these post type screens. This function can be used to remove any meta boxes conditionally

```
<?php
if (is_admin()) :
function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
    if( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
    $custom_post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ), 'objects');

        foreach ( $custom_post_types as $custom_post_type ) {

            $exclude = array( 'information' ); //<---Replace information with your own post type

            if( TRUE === in_array( $custom_post_type->name, $exclude ) )
            continue;

            $posttypes = $custom_post_type->name;

            remove_meta_box('tagsdiv-post_tag', $posttypes, 'normal');
        }
    }
}
endif;

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
```

Comment: Definitely a tad over complex :)

Comment: Hahaha, thought so. Great that one of the other answers helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check either the current post is `airports` or not.

This can be done like this:

```
function custom_remove_tag_box() {
    global $current_screen;
    if ( $current_screen->post_type != 'airports' ) {
        remove_meta_box('tagsdiv-post_tag', 'post', 'normal');
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_remove_tag_box');
```

Tested and working.

Comment: Ah, simple as that, thanks! I'm just leaving the office for the weekend (bad timing) but will be picking this up again Monday, so will report back then ;)

Comment: This cannot work. `admin_init` does not pass a `WP_Post` object.

Comment: @toscho Thanks for pointing out. I have updated my code, and looks like it's working for me (tested).

Comment: Replacing ```add_action('admin_head', 'custom_remove_tag_box');``` with ```add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_remove_tag_box');``` got it working.